# Find ES bottleneck in bulk (bigdesk screenshots attached)

Tags: amazon-ec2, lucene, elasticsearch

**Updated: Beware long post**

Before I go big and move to a bigger server I want to understand what's wrong with this one.

This is an MVP of an elasticsearch server in AWS (EC2). Two micro-s with just 600mb ram each.

I want to understand what's wrong with this configuration. As you can see there's  a bottlenecking in the bulk command. The OS memory is quite full, heap memory is still low and although the process CPU is running at maximum, the OS cpu is low.

I reduced the complexity of each document in the bulk-feed and set unwanted field to not be indexed. The screenshots below is my last attempt.

Is it an I/O bottleneck? I store the data on a S3 bucket.

[image]
[image]

### Server Info:

2 Nodes (one in each server), 3 indexes each of them running with 2 shards and 1 replica. So it's a primary node with a running backup one. Strangely "Iron man" node never took over a shard.

[image: VISUALIZATION]

I run again the feeder with the above cluster state and the bottleneck seems to be on both nodes:

*Here is the beginning of the feeder:*

**Primary**:

[image: PARENT]

**Secondary** (secondary has the bottleneck):
[image: SECONDARY]

---

*After 5 minutes of feeding:*

**Primary** (now primary has the bottleneck)

[image]

**Secondary** (secondary now is better):

[image]

---

I'm using py-elasticsearch so requests are auto-throttled in the streamer. However after the big bottleneck below it threw this error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
ConnectionError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='IP_HERE', port=9200): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=10)) caused by: 
ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='IP_HERE', port=9200): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

And here below is a very interesting screenshot on the same "bulk-feed". The Queue reached 20, the python threw the expression above and the `refresh` command runs until now that I'm writing.

[image]

---

My objective is to understand which source (CPU, RAM, Disk, Network...) is the inadequate or even better to use the existing sources more efficiently.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information regarding your cluster? Number of nodes, shards and replicas?

Comment: @Nate Updated. And gave more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run the [IndexPerfES.sh script](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/?wpdmact=process&did=My5ob3RsaW5r) against index you are bulk indexing to, we can then see if the performance improves. I think that the refresh rate is degrading performance and is perhaps causing stress on the cluster, leading to problems. Let me know and we can work this out.

Comment: Indeed it was the refresh rate.Thanks a lot! Side question: Is closing index necessary or can I "hot-apply" the settings before and after the indexing?

Comment: Closing the index is necessary for some of the options, I can't remember which now if alter the query it will tell you on the stack trace. Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

So Nate's script was (among others) reducing the refresh interval. Let me add some other findings as well:

The refresh rate was stressing the cluster however I continued searching and found more "errors". One gotcha was that I have a deprecated [S3.Gateway](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws#s3-gateway). S3 is persistent but slower than the EC2 volume.

Not only did I have S3 as data storage but on a different region (ec2 virginia -> s3 oregon). So sending documents over the network. I got down to that because some old tutorials have S3 as cloud data storage option.

After solving that, the "Documents deleted" below was better. When I was using S3 it was like 30%. This is from Elasticsearch HQ plugin.

[image: FS Ops]

Since now we have optimized I/O. Let's see what else we can do.

I found out that CPU is an issue. Although big desk says that the workload was minimal, `t1.micros` are [not to used for persistent CPU usage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html). That means that although on the charts CPU it is not fully used that's because Amazon throttles it in intervals and in reality they are fully used.

If you put a big more complex documents it will stress the server.

Happy dev-oping.